# Looking for a way to code a command cooldown for Discord Bot

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am using Python.

Here is a sample command:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def enablesentience(ctx):
    await client.say(":desktop: | User does not have sufficient permissions.")
```

When the command 'enablesentience' is triggered, the bot says in chat:

> :desktop: | User does not have sufficient permissions.

What I am looking for is a way to add a cooldown to this command, so that a person may only use the command once every how many seconds. If the command is attempted while the cooldown is active, I want the bot to say in chat the remaining cooldown time.

I have attempted:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.server.user)
async def enablesentience(ctx):
    await client.say(":desktop: | User does not have sufficient permissions.")
```

and

```
async def cooldown(1, 5, type=server.default)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def enablesentience(ctx):
    await client.say(":desktop: | User does not have sufficient permissions.")
```

Which only gave "'Command' object has no attribute 'cooldown'" and syntax errors, respectively.

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was almost right -- you need to specify a `BucketType` to use, instead of "`commands.server.user`", like so:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
```

There are multiple buckets you can choose from. They're all in the source code [here.](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/cooldowns.py#L31) (`default` means global.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Adding "class BucketType(enum.Enum):" did not help, nor did "import enum" or replacing the BucketType variable, or even just using BucketType.